# Drag and Drop Buttons - How to get access the dropped button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want when I move button2 into button1 (img2) below code will done.

My code:

```
private void ButtonDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     var btn = (Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button)); //button2

     (sender as Button).Text = "test1"; //button1
     btn.Text = "Test2"; //button2
}
```

[image: two buttons]

How Can I make when button1 touch button2 code will done?

[image: button on button]

Comment: Presumably you would use [e.Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.drageventargs.data?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-drageventargs-data) but it really depends on how you setup the first button to be able to be dragged onto the second button. Can you show more complete code?

Comment: var btn = (Button)e.Data.GetData(typeof(Button));

Comment: Idle_Mind It is a Windows Forms applications where I have two button and I want when I drag first button into the second button they change colors

Comment: @Adrian Did Hans's answer not work for you? If so, you should provide a [repro]. Also, you might want to use the `Text` property rather than the `Name` property if you're using it for testing.

Comment: Works, but when I move button2 to button1 it didn't change the `Text`. Image above.